# Calling Functions inside iframe

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to call a function inside an iFrame. Everythings fine with the code below when I'm using Firefox but if I use IE(8) it does not work:

```
 document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.myFunction();
```

From the parent, I wanted to call the function inside the iFrame. How do I let it work in IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var _frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
var contentWin = _frame.contentWindow || _frame.contentDocument;
```

Comment: * `.contentWindow` is the part that differs

Comment: i tried that in the debug console but did not work. I got it to work with this: window.frames['iframe']window.myFunction()

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work across all browsers with this code below:

```
window.frames['iframeid'].window.myFunction();
```